# Can't post blank to database: postgreSQL and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

In my View Page, I have a blank input but whenever I have to post to my database, it gets error.

View Page:

```
<label for="column1">COLUMN1:</label> 
<input type="input" name="column1">
```

Model Page:

```
 'column1' => $this->input->post('column1'),
```

This code will not satisfy if my input is blank. How can I post it to my database with the value of 0 instead of blank(cause it will not satisy).

Column1 is an integer type so blank value in not an integer as what I understand. Can anyone help me.

BTW I'm using Codeigniter and PostgreSQL

EDIT------- MY REAL CODE

Model

```
 public function changeNow_table2_A(){
 $seq = $this->input->post('seq');
 $data = array(

   'tech_voc' => $this->input->post('tech_voc'),
   'bacc' => $this->input->post('bacc'),
   'post_bacc' => $this->input->post('post_bacc'),
   'llb' => $this->input->post('llb'),
   'md' => $this->input->post('md')

 );

   $this->db->where('seq', $seq);
   $this->db->update('table2', $data); 
 } // this work
```

I tried changing only

```
'bacc' => empty($this->input->post('bacc'))? 0 : $this->input->post('bacc'),
    // changing 'bacc' to this, it gets server error.
```

Comment: Prior to version 5.5 the `empty` function only supports variables - you are passing it a function and therefore will throw a fatal error (if you are using a version of php older than 5.5). As of version version 5.5 the `empty` function also supports expressions. See the documentation: http://us1.php.net/empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you resolved this yet - just in case, here is another answer.

```
$column1 = $this->input->post('column1');
$data = array('testcol' => 'testing',
          'column1' => (empty($column1) || !is_numeric($column1)) ? 0 : $column1);
```

This will set `column1` to 0 if column1 is empty or if column1 is not a number

---

Prior to version 5.5 the `empty` function only supports variables. Meaning `empty($this->input->post('field'))` will throw a fatal error. PHP 5.5 included support for using expressions as arguments to `empty`. The error was most likely a result of using a function as an argument to the `empty` function. Check your version of php to confirm this.

here is the php empty [documentation](http://www.php.net/empty)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a ternary operator.

```
'column1' => empty($this->input->post('column1'))? 0 : $this->input->post('column1'),
```

Comment: Did you use the code correctly ? Can you post your code ?